# For loop for iterating between dates

Tags: r, function, loops, date, iterable

I have the following function that gathers data and parses them to dataframes.

```
 df <- read_URL('2019-01-15','2019-01-01', token = token)
```

Now i want to iterate this function between a range of the following dates, and bind all the dataframes together. The dates:

```
 start_dates <- c(seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-06-01"), by = "month"))
 end_dates <- start_dates + 15
```

I have written a for loop but unfortunately it does not work. My for loop is:

```
 mytempfile <- tempfile()


for (start_date in start_dates){
  for (end_date in end_dates){
    df <- read_URL(start_date,end_date, token = token)
    data <- rbind(df,mytempfile)
  }
}
```

Also please note that the function is irrelevant as it obviously works before trying the for loop, and i'm not including it for confidential reasons. 
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like creating a data.frame of your combinations, which also allows you to track your list:

```
dates_df = expand.grid(start=start_dates,end=end_dates)

data = lapply(1:nrow(dates_df),function(i){

    read_URL(dates_df$start[i],dates_df$end[i], token = token)
})

data= do.call(rbind,data)
```

I cannot test this code because the example you have is not reproducible. If you can provide one, it would help a lot.